# Bizarre React.createElement Error (Invariant Violation)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mocha.js, react-router

I am getting an error that I cannot explain when testing my components in mocha.  The relevant code is:

```
  console.error('Index', Index, typeof Index);
  let ind = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Index />);
```

which is producing:

> ERROR: 'Index', function Index() { ... }, 'function'
>
> ERROR: 'Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Index`.'

So it seems that on the first line `Index` is a function, and on the very next line, it is now an object.

I have never seen this sort of error before and cannot for the life of me begin to guess what is causing it.  I'm using webpack and react-router, but I'm not sure how those could be relevant to this error (the same setup has never caused this sort of error before).

What could cause the type of my component to change from one line to the next?  Or at least, what could cause React.createElement to think it has changed?

EDIT:

Found the error.  The error was not in `Index.jsx` the way the error seemed to imply.  The error was in a component that `Index` imported and rendered in its render method.

Comment: It's something inside the Index render method, as the error says, not the Index itself

Comment: Please share your `Index` component and `render` method in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time this happens (well to me) is because you haven't exported / imported correctly.

Common error (for me):

```
// File: LeComponent.js
export class LeComponent extends React.Component { ... }

// File: App.js
import LeComponent from './LeComponent';

// no "default" export, should be  export default class LeComponent
```

There a few ways it could be wrong, but that error is because of an import/export mistake 60% of the time, everytime.

Comment: This turned out to be the problem, except it wasn't `Index` that was imported incorrectly.  It was one of the components that `Index` depended on, which the error message did not make clear.